Background image - APEX
I'm having trouble displaying a background image in a static content region in Oracle APEX. I have assigned a static_id to the region, and the image is stored in the "Static Application Files" section.
Here's the CSS I'm using:
#divPhoto { 
    background-image: url(#APP_FILES#background.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 624px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100% !important;
    min-height: 350px !important;
    max-height: min-content !important;
    background-size: cover !important;
}

However, the image is not displaying as expected. It appears zoomed in or cropped, and not at the original scale or aspect ratio that it has in the file.
I've tried setting background-size: contain; as well, but it still doesn't match the image dimensions correctly. What might I be missing here?
